# Replace values in NumPy array based on dictionary and avoid overlap between new values and keys

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to replace values in a 2D numpy array based on following dictionary in python:

```
code    region
334     0
4       22
8       31
12      16
16      17
24      27
28      18
32      21
36       1
```

I want to find cells in `numpy` 2D array which match `code` and replace by corresponding value in `region` column. The issue is that this will result in replacing `code = 12` by `region = 16` and in the next line, all cells with value of 16 (including the ones which just got assigned a value of 16) will be replaced by a value of 17. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: `df['your_col'].map(df2.set_index('code'))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one based on [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to trace back the locations for each of those keys in the array and then replacing and please excuse the almost *sexist* function name here (couldn't help it though) -

```
def replace_with_dict(ar, dic):
    # Extract out keys and values
    k = np.array(list(dic.keys()))
    v = np.array(list(dic.values()))

    # Get argsort indices
    sidx = k.argsort()
    
    # Drop the magic bomb with searchsorted to get the corresponding
    # places for a in keys (using sorter since a is not necessarily sorted).
    # Then trace it back to original order with indexing into sidx
    # Finally index into values for desired output.
    return v[sidx[np.searchsorted(k,ar,sorter=sidx)]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [82]: dic ={334:0, 4:22, 8:31, 12:16, 16:17, 24:27, 28:18, 32:21, 36:1}
    ...: 
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.choice(dic.keys(), 20)
    ...: 

In [83]: a
Out[83]: 
array([ 28,  16,  32,  32, 334,  32,  28,   4,   8, 334,  12,  36,  36,
        24,  12, 334, 334,  36,  24,  28])

In [84]: replace_with_dict(a, dic)
Out[84]: 
array([18, 17, 21, 21,  0, 21, 18, 22, 31,  0, 16,  1,  1, 27, 16,  0,  0,
        1, 27, 18])
```

**Improvement**

A faster one for big arrays would be sort the values and keys arrays and then use `searchsorted` without `sorter`, like so -

```
def replace_with_dict2(ar, dic):
    # Extract out keys and values
    k = np.array(list(dic.keys()))
    v = np.array(list(dic.values()))

    # Get argsort indices
    sidx = k.argsort()
    
    ks = k[sidx]
    vs = v[sidx]
    return vs[np.searchsorted(ks,ar)]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [91]: dic ={334:0, 4:22, 8:31, 12:16, 16:17, 24:27, 28:18, 32:21, 36:1}
    ...: 
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.choice(dic.keys(), 20000)

In [92]: out1 = replace_with_dict(a, dic)
    ...: out2 = replace_with_dict2(a, dic)
    ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
True

In [93]: %timeit replace_with_dict(a, dic)
1000 loops, best of 3: 453 µs per loop
    
In [95]: %timeit replace_with_dict2(a, dic)
1000 loops, best of 3: 341 µs per loop
```

**Generic case when all array elements are not in dictionary**

If all elements in the input array are not guaranteed to be in the dictionary, we need a bit more work as listed below -

```
def replace_with_dict2_generic(ar, dic, assume_all_present=True):
    # Extract out keys and values
    k = np.array(list(dic.keys()))
    v = np.array(list(dic.values()))

    # Get argsort indices
    sidx = k.argsort()

    ks = k[sidx]
    vs = v[sidx]
    idx = np.searchsorted(ks,ar)

    if assume_all_present==0:
        idx[idx==len(vs)] = 0
        mask = ks[idx] == ar
        return np.where(mask, vs[idx], ar)
    else:
        return vs[idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [163]: dic ={334:0, 4:22, 8:31, 12:16, 16:17, 24:27, 28:18, 32:21, 36:1}
     ...: 
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.choice(dic.keys(), (20))
     ...: a[-1] = 400

In [165]: a
Out[165]: 
array([ 28,  16,  32,  32, 334,  32,  28,   4,   8, 334,  12,  36,  36,
        24,  12, 334, 334,  36,  24, 400])

In [166]: replace_with_dict2_generic(a, dic, assume_all_present=False)
Out[166]: 
array([ 18,  17,  21,  21,   0,  21,  18,  22,  31,   0,  16,   1,   1,
        27,  16,   0,   0,   1,  27, 400])
```

Comment: thanks @Divakar, this is a really comprehensive soln!

Comment: this one is a highly comprehensive solution. I wonder if in the second case (all array elements are not in dictionary), how can I change all of those out-of-dict element into other values? Such as `-1`

Comment: I suggest that instead of using == operator to create mask array (ks[idx] == ar), we should use `np.isin(ar,ks[idx])`. This is because when I tried in goolge colab, your code worked well, but when I tried in my local machine, it did not create a new array. 
Thank you for your code.
Here is my code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lLg5yQQs5_Ru1cOVDfNezWGYdQkpIO4z?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is in two passes: first, get the indexes corresponding to the values you want to replace, and then replace the values.

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3])
code = np.array([1,2])
region = np.array([2,3])
index_list = []
for val in code:
     index_list.append(np.where(arr == val)[0])
for indexes, replace_val in zip(index_list, region):
    arr[indexes] = replace_val
```

Comment: Why are you using np.where inside a loop?

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? I couldn't find a method to get the indices of multiple values in an array at the same time.

Comment: I didn't really look at what you're trying to do, but generally using a loop with numpy methods is an anti pattern.

Comment: The first `for` loop gets the indicies for each value in `code`. Then, the next `for` loop replaces the indicies for each value in `code` with their replacement values in `region`. Is there a better way to do this without loops?

Comment: Yes, you could perhaps look at `df.map`.

Comment: Ah, I he didn't mention pandas in his post so I avoided using it, but I see he tagged it as such. `map` would definitely be the superior option here. I tried getting `vectorize` to work, but it doesn't like when the return function is a numpy array, and in it's implementation it states that it is basically a `for` loop anyways.