# Convert elements in a tensorflow array using a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a tensorflow array and I want to convert each one of it's elements to another element using a dictionary.

Here is my array:

```
elems = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

and here is the dictionary:

```
d = {1:1,2:5,3:7,4:5,5:8,6:2}
```

After the conversion, the resulting array should be

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1, 5, 7, 5, 8, 2]))
```

In order to do that, I tried to use `tf.map_fn` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

d = {1:1,2:5,3:7,4:5,5:8,6:2}

elems = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
res = tf.map_fn(lambda x: d[x], elems)
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(res))
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

> ```
> squares = tf.map_fn(lambda x: d[x], elems) KeyError: <tf.Tensor 'map/while/TensorArrayReadV3:0' shape=() dtype=int64>
> ```

What would be the correct way to do that? I was basically trying to follow the usage from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn).

P.S. my arrays are actually 3D, I just used 1D as an example since the code fails in that case as well.

Comment: Here's a NumPy solution for arrays - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171356/.

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the link! In my case this is a part of a bigger tensorflow code, so I do not want to transfer the array each time to a numpy array and then back to a tensor. I was hoping that there would be some direct way to do that without doing a translation.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a `tf.data.*` pipeline of which this is an intermediate step?

Comment: Are your keys going to be 0..n, or are they going to be more complicated ?

Comment: @gdelab no the keys would be just some set of non-negative integers, something like [0,14,30,55]. So they won't be consecutive.

Comment: @GPhilo no this is not part of a tf.data.* pipeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`tensorflow.contrib.lookup.HashTable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/HashTable):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

d = {1:1,2:5,3:7,4:5,5:8,6:2}
keys = list(d.keys())
values = [d[k] for k in keys]
table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
  tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values, key_dtype=tf.int64, value_dtype=tf.int64), -1
)
elems = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), dtype=tf.int64)
res = tf.map_fn(lambda x: table.lookup(x), elems)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(table.init)
print(sess.run(res))
```