# Replace numpy 2D array numbers according numbers in df columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have 2D numpy array with some numbers and also a have df with two columns. I need to replace all numbers in 2D array according old/ new labels pair in df. How can I do that?

```
np.random.randint(15, size = (2,100))
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'old labels' : range(0,15 ,1),
    'new labels' : random.sample(range(0,15), 15)})
```

Comment: I think this is a comprehensive answer for you.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171648/10888655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, given

```
arr = np.random.randint(15, size = (2,100))
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'old labels' : range(0,15 ,1),
    'new labels' : random.sample(range(0,15), 15)})
```

And assuming we have only two dimensions.

```
d = df['new labels'].to_dict()
arr = np.array([d[x] for y in arr.tolist() for x in y]).reshape(arr.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a mapping.  Using numpy tricks and efficiency :

```
data= np.random.randint(15, size = (2,100))
map= df['new labels'].values
result = map[data]
```